# Github doesn't display image file, which is defined in Readme.md

Tags: image, github, package, r-markdown, markdown

I was writing a R package and wanted to display a image (plot) in the Readme section of a GitHub repository. The `Readme.md` was generated by using the knitting function of `RMarkdown`.

[image: HTML output of knit function]

After knitting the `Readme.Rmd` I commited all generated image file and pushed them to my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Wei-Lim/lighting/).

In the generated `Readme.md` file the following code section for the image was created.

> ...
> Plot light distribution (polar chart)
>
> Plots a typical light distribution data.
>
> r
> plot_light_distribution(ld_list$lum_int_extended_tbl)
>
> ```
> <img src="man/figures/README-unnamed-chunk-2-1.png" width="100%" />
>
> Write LDT, convert to IES and export to SVG
> ...
> ```

Unfortunately, the image isn't display on the Readme section. But it is downloadable from Github, following the underlying link.

[image]

Can somebody help me on this topic, please?

Comment: I am seeing the image in your repo right now! Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdyql.png)

Comment: Indeed, it is as you say. Apparently, it takes some time (probably 1 day) for the link to the image file to show up on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that after committing and uploading a new image file, GitHub needs some time to render the image to be displayed. The image showed up a day after it was uploaded.

Thanks to shafee for the notification